# Evaluate coefficients of delta functions in a given expression

Tags: functions, replacement, expression-manipulation

Suppose that I have a function of the form:

```
myfn[x_] = smoothfn[x] + A[x] DiracDelta[x-x0] + B[x] DiracDelta'[x-x0],
```

where `smoothfn` is some smooth function.

It is a well-known result that for any smooth function $F(x)$, we have the following properties:

$$ F(x) \delta(x-x_0) = F(x_0) \delta(x-x_0), \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad F(x) \delta'(x-x_0) = -F'(x_0) \delta(x-x_0) + F(x_0) \delta'(x-x_0). $$

(This can be checked by integrating both sides against an arbitrary test function).
I would like to implement a function in Mathematica, `myop`, that takes a function as its first argument (presumably one would need to reserve a second argument to tell it what the variable is) and returns the function so that all the coefficients in front of the Dirac functions (and their derivatives) are evaluated at $x_0$. In the above example, I would want something of the type:

```
myop[myfn[x],x]
(* Out: smoothfn[x] + (A[x0]-B'[x0]) DiracDelta[x-x0] + B[x0] DiracDelta'[x-x0] *)
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: That second case looks wrong. Should only be the `F'[x_0]` term, and that negated (derived by IBP). Example:`In[87]:= Integrate[f[x]*DiracDelta'[x - 2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Out[87]= -Derivative[1][f][2]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: The expression `Integrate[f[x]*DiracDelta'[x - 2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` makes no sense in traditional math.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sorry, corrected the typo.

Comment: @user64494 It makes as much sense as same but sans the prime. And I would be careful with a term like “traditional math”. It is simply unclear what assumptions are being made e.g. about f[x].